# How to bind "Hide Others" to a key "M-s-h" in railwaycat/emacs-mac-port?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm using the railwaycat/emacs-mac-port, and would like to continue use it because of the very nice smooth scrolling. Anyone knows if there is a way to have the `"M-s-h"` key work as in other Mac applications? In Cocoa emacs I can for example do `(global-set-key (kbd "M-S-h") 'ns-do-hide-others)`. Thanks

Comment: Do the functions themselves -- `ns-do-hide-others` and/or `ns-do-hide-emacs` -- work if you call them interactively?  `M-x ns-do-hide-others` and `M-x ns-do-hide-emacs`.  [Although not related to your issue, smooth scrolling is as simple as `(setq scroll-conservatively 101)` in a generic Emacs without any other settings needed.  Most newbies add other stuff that makes it not work correctly.]  When building Emacs with the option `--with-ns`, the library `ns-win.el` is used/incorporated and it has those two functions, plus a slew of `super` keybindings.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. The railwaycat/emacs-mac-port does not have the `ns-` functions. I tried to reinstall it with `brew install emacs-mac --with-ns` but the functions are still not available. It seems like my question really is how to get the `ns-` functions available in this Emacs port!

Comment: You may wish to consider modifying the question to attract someone familiar with building this particular port of Emacs.  The option/flag `--with-ns` is used when building the vanilla/generic version of Emacs from source.  I don't use brew because it puts things in different places, and I want everything in one folder so I can rsync everything to different computers and backup to different storage locations (e.g., remote and usb).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `do-applescript` command with some AppleScript to hide all other applications:

```
(defun mac-hide-others ()
  "On a Mac, hide all applications other than Emacs."
  (interactive)
  (do-applescript (concat "tell application \"System Events\" to "
                          "set visible of every process whose visible is true "
                          "and name is not \"Emacs\" to "
                          "false")))
```

If you don't want the frontmost application to be hidden (in case you are calling the command from a terminal emulator, for example, and you do not want the terminal to be hidden after executing the command), then use this slight modification:

```
(defun mac-hide-others ()
  "On a Mac, hide all applications other than Emacs and the frontmost
application."
  (interactive)
  (do-applescript (concat "tell application \"System Events\" to "
                          "set visible of every process whose visible is true "
                          "and name is not \"Emacs\" "
                          "and frontmost is false to "
                          "false")))
```

To call either of these functions with "M-s-h", use

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s-h") 'mac-hide-others)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
(setq mac-pass-command-to-system nil)
```

Comment: That makes things even worse (s-h for "Hide" stops working), never mind making M-s-h for "Hide Others" work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do this in Emacs Mac Port. You do not need AppleScript - just use this:

```lisp
(keymap-global-set "M-s-h" (lambda () (interactive) (mac-send-action 'hideOtherApplications)))
```