# how to disable command-h hide in Emacs Mac Port (railwaycat)?

Tags: key-bindings, osx, emacs-mac-port

I run Emacs on Mac OSX, I'm trying to switch from [Emacs for Mac OSX](http://emacsformacosx.com) to [Emacs Mac Port](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port). I'm having some trouble with my keybindings.

For example, I'm trying to bind command-h to `replace-string`.

```
(setq mac-command-modifier 'super)
(define-key key-minor-mode-map (kbd "s-h") 'replace-string)
```

This didn't work. So I tried binding it as hyper:

```
(define-hyper-key "h" 'replace-string)
```

but that didn't work either.

Changing other keybindings does seem to work (`s-o`, `s-p`, etc).

This may be related: [How to bind "Hide Others" to a key "M-s-h" in railwaycat/emacs-mac-port?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/how-to-bind-hide-others-to-a-key-m-s-h-in-railwaycat-emacs-mac-port)

command-h for `replace-string` works on Emacs for Mac OSX, but on Emacs Mac Port, it just hides/minimizes the application window. Do keybindings work differently in Emacs Mac Port than they do on Emacs for Mac OSX? Are some keybindings hardcoded in to Emacs Mac Port, and if so, how can I override them?

**Update**: Looks like others are having the same issue. https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port/issues/78

Comment: Do the regular stuff work?:  `(define-key global-map [?\s-h] 'replace-string)`  And, I have this for regular Emacs:  `(setq ns-command-modifier 'super)`

Comment: No, same result.

Comment: Changing other keybindings does seem to work (`s-o`, `s-p`, etc).

Comment: If other keybindings work, then how about trying `C-h k s-h` and see if it registers, or perhaps the OSX is intercepting it?

Comment: That doesn't work either. Looks like it's being intercepted. But it's something about the Emacs Mac Port application and not OSX itself, since with Emacs for Mac OSX it works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the answer.

In Emacs Mac Port, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> bypasses any Emacs keybindings and instead sends a "pass command to system" message to Mac OSX, which then hides the entire application.

This is a vestige of behavior from the old Carbon Emacs. To disable it, use this:

```
(setq mac-pass-command-to-system nil)
```

Source:

http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.emacs/2005-11/msg00091.html
http://comp.emacs.xemacs.narkive.com/dBRWEljn/apple-carbon-emacs-disable-cmd-h-hide

Comment: Thanks for this! Spent hours searching for the right answer.